# Odd return behavior with std::function created from lambda (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, g++, std-function

I'm having trouble with std::functions created from lambdas if the function returns a reference but the return type isn't explicitly called out as a reference. It seems that the std::function is created fine with no warnings, but upon calling it, a value is returned when a reference is expected, causing things to blow up. Here's a very contrived example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main(){
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.push_back(123);
   std::function<const std::vector<int>&(const std::vector<int>&)> callback =
      [](const std::vector<int> &in){return in;};
   std::cout << callback(v).at(0) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This prints out garbage, however if the lambda is modified to explicitly return a const reference it works fine. I can understand the compiler thinking the lambda is return-by-value without the hint (when I originally ran into this problem, the lambda was directly returning the result from a function that returned a const reference, in which case I would think that the const reference return of the lambda would be deducible, but apparently not.) What I am surprised by is that the compiler lets the std::function be constructed from the lambda with mismatched return types. Is this behavior expected? Am I missing something in the standard that allows this mismatch to occur? I'm seeing this with g++ (GCC) 4.8.2, haven't tried it with anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: @Nawaz Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Clang++ 3.7.0 also prints garbage (g++ lead to a segmentation fault for me).

Comment: @jhnnslschnr Thanks for checking - not sure why the posted answer was deleted (it seemed correct) but the essence was that a lambda returning a value will happily bind to a std::function with a reference return type, the end result being that the lambda returns a copy and the function returns a reference to the temporary copy. I suppose this is no different than returning a local variable from a function with a reference return type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Why is it broken?**

When the return type of a lambda is deduced, reference and cv-qualifications are dropped. So the return type of

```
[](const std::vector<int> &in){return in;};
```

is just `std::vector<int>`, not `std::vector<int> const&`. As a result, if we strip out the lambda and `std::function` part of your code, we effectively have:

```
std::vector<int> lambda(std::vector<int> const& in)
{
    return in;
}

std::vector<int> const& callback(std::vector<int> const& in)
{
    return lambda(in);
}
```

`lambda` returns a temporary. It effectively is just copied its input. This temporary is bound the reference return in `callback`. But temporaries bound to a reference in a `return` statement do not have their lifetime extended, so the temporary is destroyed at the end of the return statement. Thus, at this point:

```
callback(v).at(0)
-----------^
```

we have a dangling reference to a destroyed *copy* of `v`.

The solution is to explicitly specify the return type of the lambda to be a reference:

```
 [](const std::vector<int> &in)-> const std::vector<int>& {return in;}
 [](const std::vector<int> &in)-> decltype(auto) {return in;} // C++14
```

Now there are no copies, no temporaries, no dangling references, and no undefined behavior.

**Who's at fault?**

As to whether this is expected behavior, the answer is actually yes. The conditions for constructibility of a `std::function` are [func.wrap.func.con]:

> `f` is Callable (20.9.12.2) for argument types `ArgTypes...` and return type `R`.

where, [func.wrap.func]:

> A callable object `f` of type `F` is *Callable* for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R` if the expression
>   `INVOKE (f, declval<ArgTypes>()..., R)`, considered as an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), is well
>   formed (20.9.2).

where, [func.require], emphasis mine:

> Define `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN, R)` as `static_cast<void>(INVOKE (f, t1, t2, ..., tN))` if `R` is *cv* `void`, otherwise `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` **implicitly converted to `R`**.

So, if we had:

```
T func();
std::function<T const&()> wrapped(func);
```

That actually meets all the standard requirements: `INVOKE(func)` is well-formed and while it returns `T`, `T` *is* implicitly convertible to `T const&`. So this isn't a gcc or clang bug. This is likely a standard defect, as I don't see why you would ever want to allow such a construction. This will *never* be valid, so the wording should likely require that if `R` is a reference type then `F` must return a reference type as well.

Comment: In C++14 it can be `-> decltype(auto)`.

Comment: True about the type deduction, but you didn't answer the other half of the question. Simplified: Why is `function<const T &()>` allowed to bind to a lambda returning a `T` by value? This will *always* create a dangling reference. I'd say this is either a library bug or an oversight in the standard since this case can be checked at compile time using `decltype`.

Comment: @ArneVogel Standard defect. gcc/clang are perfectly conforming in allowing that construction. Added the wording.

Comment: We just hit this same issue with std::function directly, putting a value-returning function into a std::function returning a const-ref. MSVC 2015 diagnoses it correctly, MSVC 2013 only picks it up for function pointers, not std::bind-created objects, and neither gcc nor clang actually notice this. Is this quality-of-implementation, or a standard defect that needs to be raised?

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of my own searching regarding the `std::function` constructor. It seems this part is an oversight in the interaction of `std::function` and the standard's [`Callable` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable). `std::function<R(Args...)>::function<F>(F)` requires `F` to be `Callable` as `R(Args...)`, which in itself seems reasonable. `Callable` for `R(Args...)` requires `F`'s return type (when given arguments of types `Args...` to be implicitly convertible to `R`, which also in itself seems reasonable. Now when `R` is `const R_ &`, this will an allow implicit conversion of `R_` to `const R_ &` because const references are allowed to bind to rvalues. This is not necessarily unsafe. E.g. consider a function `f()` that returns an `int`, but is considered callable as `const int &()`.

```
const int &result = f();
if ( f == 5 )
{
   // ...
}
```

There is no issue here because of C++'s rules for extending the lifetime of a temporary. *However*, the following has undefined behavior:

```
std::function<const int &()> fWrapped{f};
if ( fWrapped() == 5 )
{
   // ...
}
```

This is because lifetime extension does not apply here. The temporary is created inside of `std::function`'s `operator()` and is destroyed before the comparison.

Therefore, `std::function`'s constructor probably should not rely on `Callable` alone, but enforce the additional restriction that implicit conversion of an rvalue to a `const` lvalue in order to bind to a reference is forbidden. Alternatively, `Callable` could be changed to never allow this conversion, at the expense of disallowing some safe usage (if only because of lifetime extension).

To make things more complicated yet, `fWrapped()` from the above example is perfectly safe to call, as long as you don't access the target of the dangling reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
return std::ref(in);
```

In your lambda it will work.

This will make your lambda's return type a `std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>` which is implicitly convertible to `std::vector<int>&`.