# Assigning std::function<int(int)> to std::function<const int&(const int& x)>

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code compiles but yields undefined output in VC++ 2015 (release) and a runtime error with [other compilers](http://ideone.com/AjjV7F).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> f = [](int x) { return x; };
    std::function<const int&(const int& x)> g = f;
    std::cout << g( 42 ) << std::endl;
}
```

Why is the assignment `g = f;` allowed?

Comment: compiles and executes perfectly with apple clang

Comment: Highly relevant/possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32871606/2069064

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the equivalent code rewritten to avoid lambdas or `std::function`:

```
int f(int x) { return x; } 
int const& g(int const& x) { return f(x); }
```

This is perfectly well-formed code, that nevertheless returns a dangling reference to a temporary and thus will end up causing undefined behavior. The original code is vaid for the same reason: you can implicitly convert an object to a reference of the same type. Unfortunate, in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Your example at least [generates a warning](http://codepad.org/o6ejBjn6). The example with `std::function` does not.

Answer (score 4):

An rvalue can be bound to a `const&`.  A `const&` can be converted to an rvalue.

Examine this:

```
int f(int x){return x;}
int const& g(int const& x){ return f(x); }
```

Similarly, the call to `g` is legal, there are no errors, yet reading the result of `g(42)` is UB -- the reference dangles.

A good compiler will see the reference bound to temporary being returned and warn.

`function` simply checks if the types can be converted between; it does no lifetime analysis.  Possibly it should, as we can detect this error statically.